# KeyError in django when i try to migrate

Tags: django

everytime i try to migrate i get `KeyError: ('komaki', 'msg')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EXO\Downloads\Compressed\mathematics-main_2\mathematics-main\maths\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\EXO\Downloads\Compressed\mathematics-main_2\mathematics-main\maths\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 211, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 361, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 329, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 91, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 384, in state_forwards
    state.remove_model(app_label, self.name_lower)
  File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 128, in remove_model
    del self.models[model_key]
        ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: ('komaki', 'msg')
```

why is thi happening

Comment: Please give some more explanation than just, "it doesn't work". What command did you run? What code changes did you do?